# how to add xxxxx format in inputmask with html input pattern?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

Input mask is by default '_ _ _ _ _' this format with html pattern. My requirement is in zipcode input, I want to change above pattern to 'xxxxx' this format.

here is my code

```
<input type="text" id="zipcode" pattern="[0-9]{5}" minlength="5" maxlength="5" required />
```

js code

```
$('#zipcode').inputmask('99999');
// if I give number format in input mask, it is working good with '_ _ _' this format. But I want to show 'x' format.

$('#zipcode').inputmask('xxxxx');
```

Is there any way to change the format from _ to x
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in options to override the default underscore - https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#placeholder-1

`$('#zipcode').inputmask('99999',{ "placeholder": "x" })`

Comment: above solution is working on browser but not in android mobile.

Answer (score -1):

You could try changing `pattern="[0-9]{5}"` to `pattern="x{5}"`

My guess is that the library you're using (`inputmask`) is setting the default mask of `_____`. The `pattern="[0-9]{5}"` option allows a series of 5 digits which is why if you "give number format in input mask, it is working good."

A site like [rubular](https://rubular.com/) might be a fun playground to see what's going on.